# How to install the pyenv tools using MacPorts

Tags: python, macos, macports

I only find tutorials showing how to install the pyenv package using Homebrew, the thing is I need to use MacPorts, and it doesn't have the pyenv package. What can I do?

Comment: Is that the port py26-virtualenv you mean?

Comment: Yes, later I discover that PyEnv and Virtualenv are the same thing.I installed the py-virtualenv as you said. Sorry for being such a noob, still getting into the terms =p

Comment: _"PyEnv and Virtualenv are the same thing"_ - they are not; and it appears that [there is no](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/58186) port for [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) yet.

Comment: Simply running the [pyenv-installer](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-installer) worked for me on macOS 10.15.2 with macports (and thus XCode/Command line tools) just installed.